# Custom activity not available

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, journeybuilder, app, custom-activity

I created an API for trigger whatsapp messages. The core is to get the contact's number on a Data Extension, created an Attribute Group, but the activity doesn't shows on journey builder's canvas.

config.json:

```
{
  "workflowApiVersion": "1.1",
  "metaData": {
    "category": "message",
    "isConfigured": true
  },
  "type": "REST",
  "lang": {
    "en-US": {
      "name": "whatsapp trigger",
      "step1Label": "Configure Activity"
    }
  },
  "arguments": {
    "execute": {
      "url": "https://myurl/send-whatsapp",
      "verb": "POST",
      "format": "json",
      "inArguments": [
        {"Email":"{{Contact.Attribute.AG_tb_crud.Email}}"}
      ]
    }
  },
  "configurationArguments": {
    "applicationExtensionKey": "mykey",
    "save": {
      "url": "https://myurl/save",
      "verb": "POST",
      "useJwt": true
    },
    "publish": {
      "url": "https://myurl/publish",
      "verb": "POST",
      "useJwt": true
    },
    "stop": {
      "url": "https://myurl/stop",
      "verb": "POST",
      "useJwt": true
    },
    "validate": {
      "url": "https://myurl/validate",
      "verb": "POST"
    }
  },
  "wizardSteps": [{ "label": "Configure Activity", "key": "step1" }],
  "userInterfaces": {
    "configModal": {
      "height": 500,
      "width": 500,
      "fullscreen": false
    }
  },
  "schema": {
    "arguments": {
      "execute": {
        "inArguments": [],
        "outArguments": []
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to get config.json of your web application, does it load in browser ?

Firstly Marketing Cloud will try to access your configured url for custom activity under Installed Package.
ex: https://yourBaseUrl/config.json

**yourBaseUrl should not point until index.html**

And could you check and send your console.logs once you open Journey Builder for any errors.

Comment: in my situation, yes, on the browser the file is loaded, inside Journey Builder, it isn't

Comment: in my situation, yes, on the browser the file is loaded, inside Journey Builder, it isn't

Comment: can u paste the console logs here, if there are any errors. And please give the public url here, let me analyze once